# How to display pictures from GridFS to web browser?

Tags: python, html, mongodb, flask, gridfs

This is how I wrote the gallery function which is supposed to display images stored in MongoDB using GridFS:

```
@app.route('/gallery/<username>')
def gallery(username):
    user = db.users.find_one({'username': username})
    images = user['images']
    for img in images:
        image = grid_fs.get(img)
        base64_data = codecs.encode(image.read(), 'base64')
        image = base64_data.decode('utf-8')
    return render_template('gallery.html')
```

How am I supposed to write the HTML document in order for the photos to be displayed?

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to return data to template:

```py
return render_template('gallery.html', **images)
```

And then you can use it in your template like this:

```html
{% for img in images %}    
    <img src="data:image/png;base64, {{ img }}">
{% endfor %}
```